# Guardar hora y fecha en columnas separadas en MySQL automaticamente

Tags: mysql

Necesito guardar por separado la hora y fecha actual cuando se ejecute la consulta automáticamente pero no estoy seguro de como puedo realizar esto y si es la manera correcta en la que lo hago.

```
CREATE TABLE `prestamo_equipos`.`prestamo_usuarios` (
  `alumno_matricula` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_equipo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE(),
  `hora` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURTIME(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`alumno_matricula`, `id_equipo`));
```

Comment: no entiendo la parte de "cuando se ejecute la consulta automáticamente" que quieres guardar cuando hizo un select, insert, update?

Answer (score 0):

No se pueden usar funciones como valores por defecto para un campo. La única excepción parece ser con los campos de tipo `TIMESTAMP`:

```
`ts` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Como dices que quieres separar la fecha de la hora en dos campos, tendrás que usar un trigger o disparador:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `default_date_and_time` BEFORE INSERT ON `prestamo_usuarios` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.fecha = curdate();
    SET NEW.hora = curtime();
END
```

Además de quitar la condición de `NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE()` y `NOT NULL DEFAULT CURTIME()`